# Probability of convergence of a sequence of independent random variables is 0 or 1

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables. I know that

$P(X_n\text{ converges})=\lim_{k\to \infty} P(\bigcup_{m\ge 1} \bigcap_{n\ge m} \bigcap_{l\ge n} \{|X_l-X_n|<\frac{1}{k}\})=1-\lim_{k\to \infty} P(\bigcup_{l\ge n} \{|X_l-X_n|\ge \frac{1}{k}\} \text{ i.o })$

Hence I think I should prove that the family of events $\{E_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is independent where $E_n=\bigcup_{l\ge n} \{|X_l-X_n|\ge \frac{1}{k}\}$ and apply Borel-Cantelli Lemma. Is it true? How could I prove it?

Comment: Have you studied Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law?